# mod rewrite length

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this configuration in VirtualHost:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap mapfile txt:mapfile.txt
RewriteCond ${mapfile:$1?%{QUERY_STRING}} >""
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ ${mapfile:$1?%{QUERY_STRING}}? [R=301]
```

This works ok with this mapfile.txt

```
prueba/code.asp?id=489 /newurl
```

But with this mapfile.txt do not match:

```
prueba/code.asp?id=489 /
```

In rewrite log:

```
[07/Dec/2012:20:52:08 +0100] [rid#7f1ac2d4280/initial] (5) map lookup OK: map=mapfile[txt] key=prueba/code.asp?id=489 -> val=/

[07/Dec/2012:20:52:08 +0100] [rid#7f1ac2d4280/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/' pattern='>""' => not-matched
```

Why do not match? Is there another way to test if query length is greater than ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't match because it's doing what you are asking it to do, rather that what you expect it to do.  The map lookup works as you expect resulting in effectively:

```
RewriteCond / >""
```

However, the cond match string operator means "compare in alphanumeric sort order" and >"" can be problematic.  Why not use the regexp . which will match if it contains (at least) one character:

```
RewriteCond ${mapfile:$1?%{QUERY_STRING}} .
```